# server DNS address could not be found

Tags: networking, dns, lan

I've very serious issue with my system or network, some of the websites doesn't open and it's just displaying `server DNS address could not be found`

[image]

I've tried to change DNS settings with Google public DNS:

```
Preferred DNS server : 8.8.8.8 
Alternate DNS server : 8.8.4.4
```

And with open DNS:

```
Preferred DNS server : 208.67.222.222 
Alternate DNS server : 208.67.220.220
```

Also tried with following commands:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
ipconfig /registerdns
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /renew
NETSH winsock reset catalog
NETSH int ipv4 reset reset.log
NETSH int ipv6 reset reset.log
```

And lot more things. But could not find solution any!
I've also refereed :

[Chrome gets stuck on “server DNS address could not be found” if I tried to access a domain while connecting](https://superuser.com/questions/1118455/chrome-gets-stuck-on-server-dns-address-could-not-be-found-if-i-tried-to-acces)

[“DNS server address couldn't be found” for some websites](https://superuser.com/questions/1116083/dns-server-address-couldnt-be-found-for-some-websites)

[Site can't be reached- server DNS address could not be found](https://superuser.com/questions/1164143/site-cant-be-reached-server-dns-address-could-not-be-found)

But no luck so far, can anyone let me know, what is the issue and how can I resolve it?

**Updated:**

Sites are not working on my system are:

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/remarkable/1.7.1/remarkable.min.js

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.2/react-dom.js

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.2/react.js

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js

I've checked with my another system which has fresh OS installed, and this all sites are working perfectly on it.

Moreover, I've checked wit uninstall my antivirus, but It couldn't solve my issue.

Comment: Is the problem always the same websites?

Comment: @harrymc: yes with same websites, in addition CDN URLs doesn't load from any website.

Comment: What happens if you : (1) disable your firewall, (2) use another browser.

Comment: @harrymc: Disabled firewall and checked with Firefox. Its displaying `Server not found Firefox can’t find the server at cdnjs.cloudflare.com.`

Comment: The problem might not be on your side but with the websites you are trying to reach, or even with some firewall between you and these websites. If you could give me some URLs that don't work for you, I can try them from here. And which country are you in?

Comment: (1) Returns a ,js file so the problem might be with the cloudflare server in India, (2) Firefox can’t find the server at node-iltorb.s3.amazonaw so this site has a real problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The poster has shown two URLs that he is unable to accede and which I tried
from here (Europe):

1. The first URL was a cloudflare address that worked for me,
   so might indicate a problem with the cloudflare server in India or its cache.
2. For the second URL I got the error
   "Firefox can’t find the server at node-iltorb.s3.amazonaw",
   so this site has a real problem and was down when I tried.

The problem can also be on your side, where the usual responsible is the
anti-virus or other security software.
Booting in Unsafe mode with Network is a quick way of telling if the problem is caused by a non-Microsoft product.

Comment: Okay, I've checked with my another system, which has fresh OS installed and that sites working with it. Seems issue with system...

Comment: I would suggest a problem with the antivirus.

Comment: Try to boot in Unsafe mode with Network. That will tell if the problem is with a non-Microsoft product.

Comment: Done as requested.

Answer (score 1):

#### Server DNS address could not be found

Try reinitialising the network states. Run the following commands in an elevated `cmd` shell **in this order**:

- Reset WINSOCK entries to installation defaults:

  `netsh winsock reset catalog`
- Reset TCP/IP stack to installation defaults:

  `netsh int ip reset reset.log`
- Reset Firewall to installation defaults:

  `netsh advfirewall reset`
- Flush DNS resolver cache:

  `ipconfig /flushdns`
- Renew DNS client registration and refresh DHCP leases:

  `ipconfig /registerdns`
- Flush routing table (reboot required):

  `route /f`

Comment: Tried with as you mentioned with an order and rebooted too!!  but still it's displaying the same thing.